# Read byte array into base64 encoded image

Tags: java, json, base64, vaadin

I'm trying to read an image into a ByteArrayOutputStream and then encode the array into Base64 for sending as part of a json to my API.  I'm wanting to avoid saving it anywhere and just read it, encode, and send.  Unfortunately, when I use the ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray() as a parameter in Base64.getEncoder.encodeToString() method it returns a String that contains extra break characters '\' in the String as compared to a successful test reading from a File into Base64.

Is it possible to read directly from the byte array into base 64?  Or will I have to translate into an image then to base 64?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Getting Image from base64:

```
byte[] b = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(base64Img);
ByteArrayInputStream s = new ByteArrayInputStream(b);
return new Image(s);
```

Maybe it can help you to do the reverse.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, passing the outputstream directly into the encoder was the issue.  I added a local variable to reference the byte[] and then pass it into the encoder and it now works.

```
byte[] array = outputStream.toByteArray();
String base64String = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(array);
```